# Url rewrite with underline automaticly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite url automatically from

```
www.example.com/test.php?title=123jane
```

to

```
www.example.com/test_123jane
```

I'm using

```
RewriteRule    ^test_([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    test.php?title=$1    [NC,L]'
```

But this doesn't change it automatically.

Comment: Are you trying to use pretty URLs? If so, you have your to and from above backwards, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /test\.php\?title=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /test_%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^test_([a-z0-9]+)$ /test.php?title=$1 [L]
```

The above should work.

Comment: I have tride this but it writes url not correctly. it's looks like this: `http://www.example.com/test_123jane?title=123jane`

Comment: @RustamzadeMahammad Updated my reply. Forgot to add the `?` after `%1` in rewrite above.

Comment: @RustamzadeMahammad clear your browser caches (press Ctrl + F5; or check your browsers developer tools).